# How to keep the UL consistent when dealing with domain expert language that differs between regions

Tags: domain-driven-design

We would like to have a ubiquitous language, and keep to the terms of our domain experts but we have several experts for the same domain using different terms, these differences correlate to regions in the world (Europe, US, etc). We need to choose one for our internal communications I suppose, but is there more we can do to have everyone on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same domain (or sub-domain), in theory, to use the "ubiquitous language", these experts must also adapt their language and use a common language.

If this is not possible, maybe there are several business sub-domains. But if it's indeed a single domain and being difficult to do it in your case because the users are not part of the project, maybe it is necessary to define a basic language and provide translation files (in Europe, many languages are used)...